# Можно ли вызывать send в основном потоке? Android

Tags: android, c++, c, tcp

Нужно отправлять несколько байтов на сервер через функцию send(sys/socket.h). Она без ошибок вызывается из метода обработки нажатий(в основном потоке). Я знаю, что в Java нельзя выполнять сетевые операции в основном потоке, так как выбросится ошибка. Могу ли я вызвать отправку на C/C++? Может ли из-за этого зависнуть приложение? Если да, то как вызывать send? В java есть ExecutorService, который вызывает методы в отдельном потоке. В C/C++ я такого не нашёл.

Comment: В java, как и в С++, выполнять сетевые операции в gui потоке можно. Однако на андроиде ART выкинет исключение. В случае С++ приложение будет просто висеть, пока вызов send не отработает. Так что используйте неблокирующий ввод или выполняйте это все в фоновом потоке.

Comment: Нельзя.............